# How extract the object part of a "composed" function result of array & object?

Tags: typescript

I am calling into a function from a library that returns both an array of value *and* an object in the same result.

When you hover over the variable in VS Code  it, it shows up something like: `[string, string, string] & {name : string, address : string, city : string}`.  You can access the value for 'name' either with `map[0]` or `map.name`.

But what I'd like to do is extract the "object part" of the return value, so I can transform it into a map.

If use the function result, I get 2x the number of entries I need:

Since the function returns both an array and a map, you get a result that looks like this:

```
 let functionVal=Object.assign(["Tom","100 Main Street","Cleveland"],
  {name: "Tom", address: "100 Main Street", city: "Cleveland"});
```

Then when you convert it into a map like this:

```
 let amap =  new Map(Array.from(Object.entries(functionVal)));
```

You get six values instead of 3:

```
 Map (6) {"0" => "Tom", "1" => "100 Main Street", "2" => "Cleveland", "name" => "Tom", "address" => "100 Main Street", "city" => "Cleveland"}
```

So I am trying to figure out if there is a way to just conver the "object" part of the interesected result, and discard the array type before i convert it to a map.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained plaintext [mre] suitable for pasting into an IDE.

Comment: I would like to, but I can't figure out how to write a function which returns an expression of the form string[] & object.    The function result in question comes from the use of typechain and ethers.js, which returns results that look like this in response smart contract calls against the blockchain.

Comment: You can use `Object.assign(["a","b"],{x:0,y:1})` to get an array with extra properties, if that helps you build an example. It’s not clear to me what you mean by “extract” here.  Why can’t you “transform it into a map” as-is? What goes wrong?

Comment: OK, see example above.

Comment: what if one of your keys has a numerical value like `"51"` ? is it guaranteed the this case doesn't happen ?

Comment: No that's not assured.  I wouldn't want to just filter out any keyvalues which look like numbers.  I am hoping there is a wya to separate out the object part from the array part  before I convert into the map.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible without this assumption, because javascript just treates numerical properties of an array as array elements, so you will loose those properties if you try to remove all array elements (using array.length = 0 for example)

Comment: How strongly typed do you need the result?  I can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6PYYm) which behaves as desired at runtime, but the output type as seen by the compiler will not have any numerical keys. This isn't wrong, since values are allowed to have keys not known in the type, but it's a little less specific than it could be.  I kind of expect you care more about runtime than about the type though.  If so I could write up my answer as-is.  If not, please [edit] to clarify that you need an input of type `[string] & {51: "string"}` to have an output of type `{51: string}`.

Comment: Actually, I think the easiest way for this use case, where the function returns an array of values of a struct, and then an array of entries for the same struct, I can just iterate, for(let entry  of Object.entries(functionVal)) {...} and   ignore the first 1/2 of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mix the array behavior and the object behavior is exotic.

It works because an array in JS is primary an object (`typeof [1, 2, 3] === "object"`).

So, being an object, you can extend it with other properties.

But an array is also considered as a collection.

So, for this array :

```
const exoticArray = Object.assign(["Tom","100 Main Street","Cleveland"],
  {name: "Tom", address: "100 Main Street", city: "Cleveland"});
```

consider this :

```
for (const element of exoticArray) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

The for-of loop, is an iteration over the collection. So you loop over 3 elements.

And now :

```
for (const property in exoticArray) {
  console.log(property)
}
```

The for-in loop lets you "iterate" over the properties's object.
This time, you have 6 iterations because you really have 6 properties on this object.

Knowing that, you can reject the keys when they are numeric.

```
let res = {}

for (const property in exoticArray) {
  if (isNaN(Number(property))) {
    res = { ...res, [property]: exoticArray[property]}
  }
}

console.log("res", JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Nevertheless, I would not encourage you to use the fact that an array can be considered as an object if you want your code to be maintainable.

Comment: I think its quite exotic as well, but it is the way that ethers.js generates a returns value for a solidity function which returns a struct, soI'm just tryiing to make it into a POJO in my typscript code.